# Окончания существительных ж.р. в р.п. мн.ч. "ошибок" и "просьб"

Tags: грамматика

Слова `ошибка` и `просьба` - оба существительные женского рода первого склонения, но при этом их формы родительного падежа множественного числа: `ошибок` и `просьб`, с окончаниями `-о-` и `нулевым окончанием`соответственно.

Если это возможно, то по какому дополнительному критерию можно определить **однозначно**, какое окончание следует следует писать в том или ином слове?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обоих словах окончание - нулевое. Что тут определять - непонятно. 
В "ошибок" второе "о" - суффиксальное, беглый гласный.

Вообще вопрос не совсем понятен, Попробую угадать. Если вы о том, различаются ли понятия "нулевого окончания" и его отсутствия как такового, то я знаю о таких подходах, но смысла большого не вижу. Здесь этот вопрос не актуален, сторонники этого подхода говорят о "нулевом окончании" в тех случаях, когда слово принадлежит к изменяемым частям речи (склоняемым), и об отсутствии - во всех остальных случаях. При таком подходе легко, например, объяснить, что при спряжении глаголов меняются суффиксы, а не окончания, которых у глаголов а настоящем времени нет. Но и всё, никакой другой пользы от неё нет, да и та что есть - сомнительна. Т.е. кажется, такая система совершенно надумана. Всё это далеко за рамками обычной школьной программы.

И в любом случае, это никак не относится к вашим примерам.  У нас ***оба слова имеют нулевое окончание***.

Answer (score 1):

Эээ... Почему-то мне понятен вопрос. То, что автор запроса называет окончанием -о-, встречается, насколько я понимаю, только в двух случаях:

- существительные женского рода с суффиксом -ка: гувернантка — гувернанток
- существительные среднего рода с суффиксом -ко: солнышко — солнышек

И да, я догадываюсь, что нужно называть это явление "беглый гласный", но это не меняет сути вопроса.

Comment: Если Вы считаете, что назвать "ка" или "ко" - суффиксом лучше, чем окончанием, то вам, конечно, все понятно.

Comment: Я считаю, что надо дать ответ на вопрос - в том виде, как он задан.

Comment: Это замечательно. *"На **любые** вопросы даем **любые** ответы?** А чего ж мне-то не ответили, на мой вопрос так, как он задан?

Comment: Опять же сорри, ничего личного. Я всем отвечаю. Просто я думал, я уже дал ответ на ваш вопрос. Вообще преклоняюсь перед вашим знанием правил русского языка. Мне с вами однозначно не тягаться. Насчет "ка/ко" как суффикс - видимо, надо было сказать суффикс "к". Я думал, это не критично для данного вопроса. Вернее сказать, я вообще об этом не думал. Глобально, остаюсь при своем мнении, что прескриптивизм - это зло, что делает меня малопригодным для этого сайта.

Comment: Ладно, с тем, что вы отвечаете не на вопрос "в том виде, как задан",  а на "в том виде как, поняли", мы уже разобрались. Теперь все-таки о главном. Вы говорите об "отсутствии правила". Сформулируйте, ***для чего***.

Answer (score -1):

По зрелому размышлению, нужно наверно сказать, что единого правила нет. Если посмотреть на примеры:

*сосна - сосен*, но *волна - волн*

*свадьба - свадеб*, но *стрельба - стрельб*

получается, что описать такое правило было бы очень трудно, если не невозможно.

Comment: Правила для чего?

Comment: По моим понятиям, в этом и был вопрос. Если вы знаете, по какому правилу (автор вопроса сказал, по какому критерию) можно определить необходимость беглой гласной, то у вас есть ответ на исходный вопрос.

Comment: Правила на беглую гласную существуют в достаточных количествах. Вопрос только в том, для какого случая вы хотите применить. Правило - это когда есть несколько случаев, чем-то общим объединенных. Вот для какого случая Вы это правило ищите.

Comment: Кстати, т.н. проверочные слова вы исключаете из числа правил? "Сос**ё**нка, свад**е**бка", для "волны" и "стрельбы" таких слов нет. Это знают дети в первом-втором классе, в пятом - активно пользуются. Вы ищите правила, которые будут понятны иностранцу? Ему надо просто запомнить.

Comment: Я всегда за простоту и ясность. Вопрос был задан автором, и я не думаю, что он иностранец. Я тоже вроде местный, с пожизненным стажем. Мне понятна формулировка автора, но если вы считаете, что ее нужно формализовать и переформулировать, то я бы поставил вопрос так: "Сформировать правило, позволяющее определить, допуская ограниченное число исключений, наличие беглой гласной о/е в формах родительного падежа множественного числа для существительных женского рода первого склонения".

Comment: Насчет детского правила о проверочных словах – стыдно, но я его не помню. Единственно, мне все равно непонятно - если это правило однозначно отвечает на все, то почему вы сразу о нем не сказали?

Comment: Разве я сказал, что на **все** отвечает? Не на все, а только на те два примера, которые вы дали - и сказали, что тут нет правила. А Вы  так и не ответили, какое именно правило Вы не знаете, на что именно - и для кого. Если на корневую беглую гласную, это это не правило даже, а очевидная вещь. Школьные правила (орфограммы) обычно формулируются для того, чтобы избежать ошибок при письме. Здесь такое просто не нужно, никто не напишет "сосн"  или "волен", а если и напишет, то его быстро поправят. ***Так ответите, на что, на какую орфограмму вы ищете правило?***

Comment: Насчет искомого правила – я сделал все, что мог, чтобы выразить его словами. Я реально думал над оптимальной формулировкой. Лучше у меня уже не получится. 
Насчет очевидности – мне кажется, это очевидно только для слов, заканчивающихся на "ка". Здесь я не смог придумать ни одного исключения.

Comment: Во всех других случаях – есть слова, где я (не самый слабограмотный) действительно потерялся бы. Например, кузня и квашня. Викисловарь дает кузен и квашней. Это тот же случай, как выше – "кузен" я бы стал писать только под принуждением. В неформальном тексте я бы написал кузней и квашней, в формальном – наверно, кузень и квашней. Но даже не это главное. Самое главное, какое правило отличает кузню от квашни?

Comment: И даже ваш пример, если поискать, можно найти достаточно много случаев написания "сосн" в текстах/фразах, составленных, очевидно, носителями. А "много судьб" встречается просто сплошь и рядом. Можно достаточно уверенно предсказывать, что эта форма станет доминирующей через пару поколений. Опять же, для меня, как дескриптивиста, проблема не в этом. Я в принципе не могу согласиться с существованием неправильных форм в речи носителей языка. Другими словами – все, что говорит носитель языка, для меня автоматически правильно.

Comment: И, самое главное, я всегда буду возвращаться к исходному вопросу, каким бы он ни был. Я дал на него ответ, который, сохранив терминологию автора, можно коротко выразить так: 
Критерия, позволяющего определить однозначно, какое окончание следует писать в том или ином слове, не существует. Это невозможно.

Comment: Вы не сформулировали, на какой вопрос отвечаете, поэтому ваш ответ не представляет никакой ценности.  А все ваши разговоры о том, как надо отвечать и почему не являются предметом обсуждения. В принципе подобные вопросы можно обсуждать на мете, но в вашем случае это просто бесперспективно.

Comment: Я проголосовал за удаление Вашего ответа. Простите, сделал все, что мог, чтобы дать Вам возможность убедить меня в его ценности, Вы этим не воспользовались. Говорить же об отсутствии какого-то правила, не сформулировав, на что это правило, бессмысленно.

Comment: I appreciate it